# navigation.php not working in foldered php project

Tags: php, navigation

I have three global files Viz., header.php,**navigation.php** and footer.php in my project. I have many sections as folders. My sections are user account, Customer Details, Invoice etc.,Each section has many files. Putting all these in root directory makes me difficult in managing the project. But When I use folders for categorizing like customer,invoice and users, navigation links are not working properly. Clicking a section in navigation link for the first time works fine but accessing another section goes How to use global header,navigation,footer for the entire project.,

**User Account**

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="sections/useraccount/usergroup.php"> User Group </a></li>
   <li><a href="sctions/useraccount/newuser.php"> Create User </a></li> 
</ul>
```

**Invoice**

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="sections/invoice/newinvoice.php"> Create </a></li>
   <li><a href="sctions/invoice/bills.php"> Bills </a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use `base url` or simply try to fix the `href` options so that it remains workable on different pages

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a typo error on your second list item href="sctions/useraccount/newuser.php  it's sctions instead of sections

Comment: Hey that;s not an issue I gave it a sample of my Problem.., Actual Problem is, I use navigation.php, header.php. footer.php globally. I have folder structured project and  specified url's for li like sections/folder/file.php. For first navigation click it wont works fine. After that when I go for the next navigation link it does not works. It goes like /sections/folder/file.php/section/folder/file.php. How to resolve this dude